# Relative path in wp_register_style not working

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style, wp-register-style

I have this function:

```
function test_add_my_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style( 'test-admin-style', plugins_url('../css/style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'test-admin-style' );
}
```

but the css is not loaded in my admin area. Why?

In the html source code from the browser it looks like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='test-admin-style-css'  href='http://www.******.com/wp-content/plugins/******/includes/../css/style.css?ver=3.6.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

instead of:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='test-admin-style-css'  href='http://www.******.com/wp-content/plugins/******/css/style.css?ver=3.6.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Why is that?

how can I fix this part:

```
/plugins/*******/includes/../css/style.css
```

to the correct one:

```
/plugins/*******/css/style.css
```

Comment: I don't see a problem here, the two URLs should fetch the same file. have you actually tried to load the "faulty" url in your browser and see what error do you get?

Comment: Hmm, seems that `__FILE__` is causing the problem

Answer (score 3):

[`plugins_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)

`plugins_url( $path, $plugin );`

You can use:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'test-admin-style', plugins_url( 'plugin-unique-name/css/plugin.min.css') );
```

or you can use

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'test-admin-style', plugins_url( 'css/admin.min.css', __FILE__ ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just using

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?